# Sending Redux actions for reusable React components

Tags: reactjs, redux

If I have a React component I am using twice, how do I send actions to the store to change the relevant value for one but not the other? E.g.,

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <ComponentContainer/>
      <ComponentContainer/>
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('home')
);

//container.js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  value: state.value,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  changeValue : (value) => {
    dispatch(changeValueStore(value));
  }
})
export default const ComponentContainer = connect(mapStatetoProps)(Component)

//component.js
export default function Component(props){
  return (
    <div onClick={handleChange(props.value++)}>
      {props.value}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I isolate the two values of ComponentContainer with this structure? I realize I should be assigning the Containers ids to pass to the reducers, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is for the action object to have an additional field (say `componentId`) which would tell the reducer which component this action concerns.

Call your action creator like this from within the component

```
<div onClick={handleChange(props.value++, props.componentId)}>
```

(Notice how `componentId` is now a required prop) so

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <div>
    <ComponentContainer componentId="c1" />
    <ComponentContainer componentId="c2"/>
  </div>
</Provider>
```

You could actually reuse the reducer you already have just wrap it int another, which would call your reducer with appropriate branch of the state (matching the `componentId`)